# Why does the ipython magic function `%timeit -n1 code_block` execute `code_block` multiple times?

Tags: python, ipython, timeit

I am trying to run a particular test multiple times in `ipython` using the
`%timeit` magic function. For demonstration purposes, I will just use `-n1` instead of
`-n3` here, and use a simple `print(1)` function.

The `%%timeit` and the `%timeit` help says the following:

```
Options: -n<N>: execute the given statement <N> times in a loop. If this
value is not given, a fitting value is chosen.

-r<R>: repeat the loop iteration <R> times and take the best result.
Default: 3 (the 3 here is a typo in ipython, for which I have submitted a
PR)
```

However, if I do the following:

```
%%timeit -n1
print(1)
```

or

```
%timeit -n1 print(1)
```

it actually prints `1` 7 times in a row as follows

```
In[1]: %timeit -n1 print(1)
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
32.8 µs ± 38.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

I was expecting that because of the definition of `%%timeit`/`%timeit` it would
run the `cell` or `code` just once.

I have read this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45375047/4752883
which gives some examples of how `%%timeit` runs and the actual source code of `ipython` magic function `%%timeit`
here: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/ec3d1a11bf26a0962cb2cf55ba263b12ac023183/IPython/core/magics/execution.py#L944

where they define 2 types of loops: 1) `-n<N>` and 2) `-r<R>`.

If I just use `-n1`, it seems that it also assumes that I have used `-r7`, i.e.
`-n1` defaults to `-n1 -r7`. This means that even though I want it to run for
exactly 1 run, it will still run the `code_block` 7 times as per
https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/ec3d1a11bf26a0962cb2cf55ba263b12ac023183/IPython/core/magics/execution.py#L1021
unless I also specify `-n1 -r1`.

### Questions:

1. Why are there 2 different ways to running the `code_block` using `-n<N>` and
   `-r<R>`?
2. What is the difference between `-n<N>` and `-r<R>` and why is this
   necessary?

Comment: %timeit -r1 time.sleep(2)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These parameters are also in the [timeit module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html).

- `-n` determines how many times you run the function (or block, or whatever) *inside* the timing window.  So the stopwatch starts, the code is run `n` times, then the stopwatch ends.  You should run it enough times that the results are meaningful (`timeit` defaults to powers of 10 until 0.2 seconds have elapsed).
- `-r` determines how many of these repetitions (where repetition is "start timer, run n times, stop timer") you should do.  There is always some error due to your CPU scheduling other processes, etc., so usually you want to run it a few times and the best value of these `r` times is taken.  (`timeit` defaults to 3, and the comments in the source you link indicate that ipython does the same -- but the actual code may disagree).

In pseudo-python, you can see how `n` and `r` affect the timing process:

```
time_hist = []
for _ in range(r):
    t0 = time.now()              # Start stopwatch (.now() is not a real function)
    for _ in range(n):
        # <your code block>
    t1 = time.now()              # Stop stopwatch

    time_hist.append(t1 - t0)    # Append time delta

 return min(time_hist)           # Return the min of the r deltas
```

Comment: Thanks for replying.. actually I did check the `timeit` module in `python` as well before posting.. and did see this.. What I was wondering is why it is necessary to have 2 different options `-n` and `-r`, why not just have 1? I will check the code that you mentioned in some more detail to see if there is any difference..

Comment: I played around with the function you mentioned.. A follow up question..When using just `-n`, the fundamental reason why you might get different values when running the same function/code, is because the underlying system may be behaving slightly differently from 1 run to another. To compensate for that we can use `-n` such that the total time is ~0.2s or higher. That makes sense.. This also takes care and accounts for the fact that `CPU may be scheduling other processes, or there may be network connections or you need to access the hard-disk which may be in use by something else`

Comment: All these variabilities are accounted for by having a sufficiently large `-n` >=0.2s. As you mentioned `-r` determines how many repetitions of `-n` you are doing and its also taking care of the same variability (`CPU scheduling, Network communications, hard-disk access etc`). So if we used a sufficiently large `-r`, with `-n1`, wouldn't it just be doing the same thing? Because, fundamentally we are trying to make sure that we have sampled enough times, so that the variability in process time due to `CPU scheduling, network access, hard disk access` are accounted for..

Comment: Because regardless of whether you use `-n20 -r1`, or `-n1 -r20`, or just had 1 option which just provided an option to define the number of times the function is run, say `-l20`, they are all just doing random sampling, and capturing sufficient number of samples to have high signal/noise ratio?